# How should I load a js-function based on parameter in url?

Tags: javascript, php

***What's the correct approach of handling this? ***

What I want to do:
Let's say I have an url like:

```
http://www.domain.com/parties/
```

This link shows all parties. Each party is clickable and If a user clicks one of them (that has id 54), then this page will show:

```
http://www.domain.com/party/54
```

A page would be shown for the specific party 54.

When I'm calling `http://www.domain.com/party{id}`, I include a javascript-file. In this js-file (`party.js`) I have a function `loadParty(party_id)`.

I want to load a specific js-function that loads the actual party (54) when calling `http://www.domain.com/party/54` (I must use javascript for this (I have to retrieve info about screen resolution etc)).

Should I do?

1. var party_id = `<?php echo $get['id'];>;`
2. Use ajax to call php, that returns the value of `$_GET['id']` (and put it into the party_id - js - variable) ?

   And then call **loadParty(party_id);**

Any other thoughts?

(I'm using jQuery/CodeIgniter if it matters (I do think not))

**UPDATE**

I was just doing `<?php echo $get['id'];>;` just to show the principle of what I wanted. I would never just do that, I promise! :-)

***The more relevant code*** would be something like

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = intval($_GET['id']);
    $party = new Party();
    $party_id = $party->doPartyExists($id); //Returns 0 at false
    if (intval($party_id) === 0) {
        throw new Exception('this is not a party');
    }
}
?>
```

and then put it the `$party_id`-value into js...

Comment: var party_id = <?php echo $get['id'];>; DON'T EVER DO THAT! You are allowing someone to do an Cross-site scripting (XSS) attack - filter your ID (with casting to (int) for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@notsobestprogrammerintheword :)

Your approach is good but i have concerns about key in $_GET : it may not be 'id', but 'party' but it depends on routing configuration.
And please cast the value from $_GET to INT: make your site immune to XSS attack!

```
var party_id = '<?php echo isset($_GET["id"]) ? (INT) $_GET["id"]: 0;>';
```

Comment: Thanks! Of course. I wasn't bothering to care about validation just to desribe my scenario. I've updated my question.

Comment: Great to here that. ;)

Answer (score 1):

First
 do this -

```
<?php

    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];

?>
```

and then make call the function like this-

```
loadParty('<?php echo $id ?>');
```

No need of ajax calls. Btw, you can write both pieces of code in the same file which you load when the url is hit.